# Disable Chrome spell checking for good

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome seems to be better at spelling than me. I have version Version 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit) installed on Linux Mint. 
These are my language settings:

[image]

Still, Chrome checks everything I type for English spelling.

How can I turn any spell checks off for good?

Comment: @Jonno No I didn't I'll have to admit ... that fixed it, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome handles spell check on a per-language basis, and as such, each language you have available can have the spell check enabled or disabled as required. As such, if you wish to disable all spell checking, you need to make sure all languages have this unchecked.

You can also drag-and-drop the languages in this screen to change the priority of them.

[image]

[image]